# Proof of a weaker version of Hall's Marriage Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

> Thm: Let $G=(V_1,V_2,E)$ be a bipartite graph s.t. (*) $|V_1|=|V_2|$, so:
>   There exists a perfect matching in G $\Leftrightarrow \forall S\subseteq V_1$, 
>   $|N(S)|\ge|S|$

In this notation, $N(S)$ stands for the group of neighbours of all vertices in $S$.

Now, there's one part I'm stuck with at the proof, let me first show you guys what I've done so far:

> **"$\Leftarrow$":**
>   (1) Let $S\subseteq V_1$ and assume: $|N(S)| \ge|S|$.
>   Let's proof by complete induction on $|V_1|$ that there's a perfect matching in $G$.
>
> (2) **Induction assumption**: Assume that for each $G=(V_1,V_2,E)$ satisfying (1), s.t. $|V_1|=|V_2|< n$, there's a perfect matching in $G$.
>
> **Induction step**: Let $|V_1|=|V_2|=n$.
>
> **Case 1:** $\forall S\subseteq V_1$, $|N(S)|>|S|$.
>    this case I proved already, so no reason to rewrite it.
>   **Case 2:** $\exists S\subsetneqq V_1$ s.t. $|N(S)|=|S|$, ($S\neq \emptyset$).
>
> Denote $G_1=(S,N(S),E_1), G_2=(V_1\backslash S,V_2\backslash N(S), E_2)$.
>   $E_1$ are the edges of $G$ between $S$ and $N(S)$, and $E_2$ are the edges of $G$ between $V_1\backslash S$ and $V_2\backslash N(S)$.
>
> I want to show that there's a perfect matching In $G_1$ and in $G_2$, therefore there's a perfect matching in $G$.
>
> For $G_1$ I already proved, so we'll proceed with $G_2$:
>
> - $|V_1|=|V_2|$ and $|S|=|N(S)|$, so $|V_1\backslash S|=|V_2\backslash N(S)|$. This satisfies (*) (first line of the post).
> - since $\emptyset\neq S\subsetneqq V_1$, than $|V_1\backslash N(S)|<|V_1|=n$. This satisfies (2), and means we can almost use the induction assumption.
> - We only need to find: $\forall T\subseteq V_1\backslash S$ holds that |$N_{G_2}(T)|\ge |T|$, where  $N_{G_2}(T)$ stands for the group of neighbours of $T$ in $G_2$. That will satisfy (1) and will complete the proof.

So the last part of this quote is where I'm stuck, the other side of the proof is pretty easy and I already proved it.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is true, try taking a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all you need to show is that the inequality $N_{G_2}(U) \ge |U|$ holds for all $U \subseteq V_1 \setminus S$. Go back and reread your top paragraph which is shaded orange in your OP to see for yourself. We do this next.

Let $U \subseteq V_1 \setminus S$. Suppose that the strict inequality $|N_{G_2}(U)| < |U|$ holds.

Then on the one hand 
$N_G(U \cup S) \subseteq N(S) \cup N_{G_2}(U_2)$ [make sure you see why]
and so $|N_G(U \cup S)|$ $\le |N(S)| + |N_{G_2}(U_2)|$ $=$ $|S| + |N_{G_2}(U_2)| <
|S|+ |U|$.

On the other hand $U$ and $S$ are disjoint so $|U \cup S|=|U|+|S|$.

Can you finish from here.

> Thus if the strict inequality $|N_{G_2}(U)| < |U|$ holds then it follows that the strict inequality $|N_G(U \cup S)| < |U \cup S|$ also holds, which contradicts the original assumption that $|N_{G}(S')| \ge |S'|$ for all subsets $S' \subseteq V_1$; indeed take $S'=S \cup U$.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! when you say that the inequality is all I need to show, do you mean the other 2 satisfied conditions I mentioned are unnecessary? also, If you can please explain $N_G(U\cup S)\subseteq N(S)\cup N_{G_2}(U_2)$ it would be great (I got lost there  a little bit)